# Using Intel's App Framework with Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, jquery

This is not a question related to a specific issue. I want to know if anyone has tried writing an Android Cordova application with Intel's App Framework. This is because I tried writing an application and it fails in certain occasions. But when I write for higher versions of Android like 3.0 it works. It is strange. I want to know why it happens like that. Is it a known issue? Will someone help we with this? (Any explanation regarding this)

Comment: What kind of situations do it fail? Could you be more specific.